# Three sides $OAB, OAC$ and $OBC$ of a tetrahedron $OABC$ are right-angled triangles, $\angle AOB = \angle AOC = \angle BOC = 90^\circ$.

Tags: geometry, triangles, problem-solving, 3d

> Three sides $OAB, OAC$ and $OBC$ of a tetrahedron $OABC$ are right-angled triangles, $\angle AOB = \angle AOC = \angle BOC = 90^\circ$. Given that $OA = 7, OB = 2$ and $OC = 6$, find :- 
> $\sqrt{([\Delta OAB]^2 + [\Delta OAC]^2 + [\Delta OBC]^2 + [\Delta ABC]^2 + 37)}$

**What I Tried**: Here is a picture of the top view of the tetrahedron.

[image]

Because of the $3$rd dimension, this problem got more complicated and I cannot seem to figure out how to do it. For example is it fine to use Pythagoras Theorem on each of the triangles $OAB,OBC,OAC$ $?$ If yes, then I can find the sides of $\Delta ABC$ as in the $2$nd dimension, but that is not really going to help me finding the areas of $\Delta OAB$ , $\Delta OAC$ , $\Delta OBC$ , on the other hand I think this is getting complicated for me to understand what to be done here.

Can anyone help me? Thank You.

Comment: Hint: see [De Gua's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Gua%27s_theorem), the 3-d generalization of Pythagorean theorem.

Comment: Area of $\triangle OAB$ is $\frac12 OA\cdot OB$. Similar for the other right angle triangles

Comment: Got it, after finding out the areas of each of $OAB,OAC,OBC$ we apply De Gua's Theorem, am I right?

Comment: @Anonymous you can also apply direct formula for trirectangular tetrahedron.